# Nginx load balancer - redirect instead of passing

Tags: redirect, nginx, cdn

I have multiple CDN servers that host large files for a main site. These content servers however do not have enough space to fit all the content, so they keep only part of it.
I have Nginx in-front of all these as a load balancer, but I'd like to redirect **directly** to the file instead of using proxy_pass and streaming it through the load balancer.

What I have right now:

```
upstream cdn {
    server content01.example.com;
    server content02.example.com;
    server content03.example.com;
}

location /files {
    proxy_pass          http://cdn;
    proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real_IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_next_upstream http_404;
}
```

How can I make it send a Location header when the response is a http_200 to for example content01.example.com and try the next server in case of a http_404?

I know this might seem a bit weird, but there are no information in the back-end as to where these files exist and there's not enough time to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the [ngx.location.capture feature of the nginx LUA module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.location.capture) to send a subrequest to each upstream server until a 200 is returned. Then rewrite the URL and issue a [ngx.redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.redirect) with that server's address.

I would consider doing this with a script outside of nginx.conf.  Also, if the upstreams had some temporal stability in their responses, I would use memcache to cache the proper response so the end user would have to wait through some number of upstream queries for every hit.